# Seeking free/open software or method to view/edit PAF file in Windows 10

Tags: ancestry.com, software-recommendations, gedcom

It is 2020 and I have an old paf and ged files and would like to read and or edit for saving offline.

Is there any recent 2020 software that is not a "Pay per Use" commercial software, that can read them?

I receive a consistent Failed - Blocked on every download.

Comment: Although it was officially retired in 2013, several sites still offer PAF 5 as an _unofficial_ download. (I can confirm that PAF 5 still runs on Windows 10)  I'd advise caution though, and if you do choose to download a copy, check it thoroughly with anti-malware software.

Answer (score 5):

Ancestral Quest is built on the same codebase as PAF and is probably the easiest upgrade path for a PAF user.  See their FAQ on [Database File Formats](https://www.ancquest.com/faqs/dbformats.htm).

Ancestral Quest is a commercial product.  The full-featured version is a paid product (a one-time purchase, not software as a service), but you could try the free Ancestral Quest Basics. The FAQ discusses the advantages and disadvantages of converting your PAF file to the AQ format, or continuing to read/edit it as a PAF file. Not all of PAF's features will be available, so read the FAQ to see if using AQ Basics would meet your needs.

The [Comparison Chart](https://www.ancquest.com/CompareAQVersions.htm) shows the differences betweeen the free and paid versions of Ancestral Quest. You can click a button on that page to include a column of PAF5 features in the comparison.